# Unique factorisation domain and units

Tags: number-theory

This from an exam I’m using for revision. It’s an unseen part and I’ve made an attempt at trying to answer it.

[image]

For bi) I’ve said that in a UFD, factorisations are only unique up until their units. Therefore, there are only finitely many factorisation of $k$ for which the product of $(x-y)(x+y)=k$. Therefore, there are only finitely many solutions with $x,y\in R$.

I don’t know whether that argument is correct. I have seen somewhere that this argument can be solved graphically by drawing a hyperbola, but could someone point me in the right direction with the attempt I’ve made, or if it’s wrong, give me some tips on how to progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially correct. Your argument is telling you, that there are only finitely many possibilities for $x+y$ and $x-y$. Then you just have to note that
$$ x = \frac{1}{2}((x+y)+(x-y)), \qquad y = \frac{1}{2}((x+y)-(x-y)) $$

and hence, there are only finitely many possiblities for $x,y$.